# Enable Windows Firewall service from cmd, enable UWP apps

Tags: windows-11, windows-firewall, microsoft-store, uwp

it was an experiment with different "system optimazers". I deleted all of them after that. but,then  I was surprised: windows firewall is disabled, all UWPs apps can not be opened (include Settings and Windows Terminal), Microsoft Store disabled as well. I tried to reenable windows firewall from services.msc, but I was not successed: I could not do anything in GUI -> right-click on windows firewall service shows popup with disabled "start" button. It looks like the only way is to use command line. I tried to google without success how to run WF service from command-line, how to reenable UWP from command-line.....
Could you please help with that?

Comment: Hard to recommend solutions without knowing exactly what has been modified or disabled, so you are left, with the generic advice of performing a in-place repair upgrade to the same version of Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound is there any cmd-commands that could start a particular service for example wf-service?

Comment: Are you able to use the [Windows Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)?  Then open the image and run setup from there.  You should have the same options and dependencies should be on the installation media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following commands in elevated cmd prompt and then reboot:

•   Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
```

•   Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

```
netsh int ip reset reset.log
```

•   Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

```
netsh advfirewall reset
```

•   Flush DNS resolver cache:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

•   Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

```
ipconfig /registerdns
```

•   Flush routing table (reboot required):

```
route /f
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to open the Windows Firewall App and reset to default?  It appears not, but I wanted to check.

System Optimzers are often snake oil, so they may not have removed cleanly.  Your post indicates this is the situation.

You may ultimately need to back up all your data and reinstall Windows.  You can try a Windows 10 Repair Install and Keep just Data but this also keeps the user profile and so I still think a proper reinstall is best here.

Comment: the problem is I could not reinstall win11: all repair function are started from "Settings" UWP app, but now all UWP's apps are not able to start at all.  So, may be just simple cmd commands could start windows firewall service?

Comment: You can back up your documents. Then you should be able to do a completely fresh install of Windows. The errors above should not prevent a fresh install.